# Storing pdf file inside sql server using nhibernate, byte[] value exceeds

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate

I want to store pdf file inside sql server 2008R2. ORM is nhibernate so my property is

```
public virtual byte[] PDFFile { get; set; }
```

and it is mapped like

```
Property(x => x.PDFFile);
```

inside database column is of type `varbinary(MAX)`

I think problem resides in the mapping of this property but I dont know how to overcome this.

On upload I'm getting

> The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length configured in the
>   mapping/parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by nHibernate limiting the length of that column type to 8000.

You can get round this by changing your fluent mapping to this:

```
Map(x => x.PDFFile).CustomType("BinaryBlob").Length(100000);
```

Where you can set the length to be whatever works for you although typically it should be int.MaxValue or less.